# What is the latest version of Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, version, msdn

According to [stuff on the net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx) it's 6.1.2 but according to version number in the files I've got from my coworker, it's higher than so.

EF is delivered by Microsoft so MSDN should be the right place to check. Isn't it?

Please note that I'm not talking abut the Azurific preview version 7. I'm talking about version 6 but a later subversion. Who do we trust here?

Comment: On Nuget packet manager the latest stable version is 6.1.3. The pre-release version is 7.0.0

Comment: wondering the same thing

Comment: 7.0.0 was renamed to "core".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question as asked will only ever make sense at a given point in time. The accepted answer is already out of date. If the question is restructured as 'where do I find out the latest version of EF' it can be reopened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 6.1.3 is the latest version at this time, released back in March, and at least officially mentioned in Monday's RTM of VS2015 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2015/07/20/entity-framework-and-visual-studio-2015-rtm.aspx

However, 6.1.3 is mostly minor bug fixes, which is why there was little fanfare and mention I believe.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best place to check is Nuget !

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework

Currently 6.1.3 today

Comment: Or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/ for ef-core.

Answer (score 0):

Now latest version as of current date is **6.2.0**.

Just for information: Although EF Core was initially named as EF 7.0, yet keep in mind that  EF Core is entirely different code base with latest version **2.1.1** as of date. More details on EF core can be found at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/